How to generate an array which is a multiple of original?
I'm trying to upsize OpenCV images in Python in such a manner that the individual pixels are spread out by an integral factor; I use this to visually examine deep detail and individual pixel values can be seen (using cv2.imshow in this instance).
For example, an array:
    [[1,2],
     [3,4]]


And a factor of 2 means I'd get:
    [[1,1,2,2],
     [1,1,2,2],
     [3,3,4,4], 
     [3,3,4,4]]


I've done this by generating an array of size*factor using np.zeros, then iterating each point in the original array and copying it to the target array using (for example)
for y in range(src.shape[0]):
    for x in range(src.shape[1]):
        tgt[y*f:y*f+f, x*f:x*f+f, :] = src[y,x,:]

But as you can imagine, it's not the fastest approach, and I'm hoping I'm just not finding the right thing.
OpenCV (and PIL) do not have a resize capability that doesn't interpolate by one method or another, which seems weird all by itself.
I looked over & tried numpy broadcast*, numpy stride_trickks, opencv functions, PIL functions.
The semi-manual method works as long as I don't need interactivity, but I'm trying to adjust parameters to several opencv functions quickly so I can find the right combinations to solve my problem.  (Which is proprietary, so I can't share imagery...)  Waiting a significant time between results is counterproductive.

You can use opencv's cv.resize with nearest-neighbor as interpolation method (cv.INTER_NEAREST) to achieve what you need:
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

src = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
dst = cv.resize(src, (4,4), interpolation=cv.INTER_NEAREST)
print(dst)

Output:
[[1 1 2 2]
 [1 1 2 2]
 [3 3 4 4]
 [3 3 4 4]]

Live demo

Thank you.  I'm embarrassed to say that I tried this but thought it didn't work.
I just tried again with a 20x resize and it's clearly working as I require.

@SBixby great! No need to be embarrased ... we all make mistakes.

You could also use np.kron:
factor = 2

np.kron(src, [[1]*factor]*factor)
 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])


Yet another option would be using numpy.repeat(). Unfortunately, here one needs to loop over all array axes, as the axis argument supports scalars only:
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
factor = 2

for axis in range(a.ndim):
    a = np.repeat(a, repeats=factor, axis=axis)

print(a)
# [[1 1 2 2]
#  [1 1 2 2]
#  [3 3 4 4]
#  [3 3 4 4]]

